# Prompt to install ActiveX not showing

Tags: asp.net, activex

I've written an ASP.net site that requires the use of a 3rd party ActiveX control.

Everything works as expected however when a new user visits the page for the first time they do not get a firts time prompt to install the activeX control. (the yellow bar in IE).

Where do i begin troubleshooting ?

Comment: We need more general detail about the box to start off. I'd tell you what to provide, but you probably already know what kind of info we need .... Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think he means it happens on any box, not just a specific one.

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify that indeed this only occurs on a PC which has not yet visited the site - Any PC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out,

For some reason referencing the OCX in the root of the application does not call the first time install.

None of the following work in the HTML markup

`<OBJECT ID="xxx" classid="xxx" CODEBASE="/axcontrol.ocx"></OBJECT>`

`<OBJECT ID="xxx" classid="xxx" CODEBASE="~/axcontrol.ocx"></OBJECT>`

`<OBJECT ID="xxx" classid="xxx" CODEBASE="../axcontrol.ocx"></OBJECT>`

But if i place the ocx in the same folder as the host ASPX page and set the CODEBASE="axcontrol.ocx" it works fine

Answer (score 0):

In the Internet Properties on a users computer, there are various security settings regarding ActiveX controls, and if the browser will automatically download and run, prompt to download and run, or just not do anything with them.

These settings can be adjusted for both Internet and Local Intranet, so it might be that you will need to change the level of security?

Comment: it's nothing to do with IE settings, i've setup some VMs and without changing IE if i manually register the ocx at command prompt it works